# Flutter: All ListTile Items responding same click

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-layout

I am new to flutter so I was trying to build a scrollable listtile objects. So after building it I tried to make the iconbutton change color when onpressed which works but when I press a single button it changes the colors of all the items. I guess it has to do with assigning a unique id/key to each of the items but am not sure if thats the issue or even how to do that. The code is below:

```dart
class Lists extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListsState createState() => _ListsState();
}

class _ListsState extends State<Lists> {
  Color _statusColor = Colors.grey;

  List<ItemLists> items = [
    ItemLists(
      title: 'Best Music of the Year',
      discription: 'Davido',
    ),
    ItemLists(
      title: 'Best Album Cover design',
      discription: 'Brighter Press',
    ),
    ItemLists(
      title: 'Best Vocalist',
      discription: 'Simi-Sola',
    ),
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
        children: items.map(
              (items) {
            return Container(
                child: Card(
                    child: ListTile(
                      leading: new IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.star,
                            color: _statusColor,
                          ),
                          tooltip: 'Add to Favorite',
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              if (_statusColor == Colors.grey) {
                                _statusColor = Colors.green;
                              } else {
                                _statusColor = Colors.grey;
                              }
                            });
                          }),
                      title: Text('${items.title}'),
                      subtitle: Text('${items.discription}'),
                      trailing: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.delete), onPressed: null),
                    )));
          },
        ).toList());
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Below is the edited code

```dart
class Lists extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListsState createState() => _ListsState();
}

class _ListsState extends State<Lists> {
  Color _statusColor = Colors.grey;

  List<ItemLists> items = [
    ItemLists(
      title: 'Best Music of the Year',
      discription: 'Davido',
      favorite: false,
    ),
    ItemLists(
      title: 'Best Album Cover design',
      discription: 'Brighter Press',
      favorite: false,
    ),
    ItemLists(
      title: 'Best Vocalist',
      discription: 'Simi-Sola',
      favorite: false,
    ),
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
        children: items.map(
              (items) {
            return Container(
                child: Card(
                    child: ListTile(
                      leading: new IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.star,
                            color: items.favorite ? Colors.green : Colors.grey,
                          ),
                          tooltip: 'Add to Favorite',
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              items.favorite = !items.favorite;
                            });
                          }),
                      title: Text('${items.title}'),
                      subtitle: Text('${items.discription}'),
                      trailing: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.delete), onPressed: null),
                    )));
          },
        ).toList());
  }
}
```

Then below is my data model

```dart
class ItemLists {
  String title;
  String discription;
  bool favorite;

  ItemLists({this.title, this.discription, this.favorite});
}
```

What am trying to do is a Todo app where the user can easily click the star iconbutton when he or she is done with a particular task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you only have one color variable assigned to all the items in your list; if that variable changes, all items changes too.

There are diffrent ways how to solve this; one possible solution would be to add another property to your 'itemlists' object:

```
List<ItemLists> items = [
ItemLists(
  title: 'Best Music of the Year',
  discription: 'Davido',
  favorite: false,  // add this as a boolean to indicate if the item is a favorite or not
),
```

then change your card like this:

```
 return Container(
          child: Card(
              child: ListTile(
        leading: new IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.star,
              color: items.favorite ? Colors.green : Colors.grey,  // change this
            ),
            tooltip: 'Add to Favorite',
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                items.favorite = !items.favorite; // and change this
              });
            }),
        title: Text('${items.title}'),
        subtitle: Text('${items.discription}'),
        trailing: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.delete), onPressed: null),
      )));
```

This should work.

Comment: i changed them but got this error [Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null]

Comment: Where is this error coming form? Have you assigned 'false' to the favorite property or use 'false' as default value?

Comment: i will edit the initial question and add the new code

Comment: Can you have a look at the stacktrace and check where the error occurs? I copied the above code and it worked for me without any problems.

Comment: it's working now... i just had to restart my system and everything works fine now

Comment: what if i want every item to have like a unique id/key so that i will be easy to store them in a database?

Comment: sorry for all the question but i have 1 extra question... if you watch in my code i forgot to use ListView.builder before adding my ListTile widget... is is a bad thing to do? will it restrict me from adding other feature to the list? ... because i have been trying to wrap my Card widget with a widget and rename it to ListView.builder but its not working and am tempted to leave it like that

Comment: Glad it worked. I found this in the offical documentation `List tiles are typically used in ListViews, or arranged in Columns in Drawers and Cards.`, so I guess it is ok to use it in a `column`. But you could also just wrap a `Listview` arround the `Listtile`. Generating a unique id would be a something that I expect from your backend.